# Zend Framework compound primary key update

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

For a project I need to update a row where the PK contains two columns.

At first I thought I should do it like this but it gives me errors. Anybody with a solution?

```
$data = array('foo','bar');
$where = $this->_getGateway()->getAdapter()
                    ->quoteInto(array('customerId=?','date=?'), array($comment->customerId, $comment->date));
$this->_getGateway()->update($data, $where);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
$whereId = $this->_getGateway()->getAdapter()->quoteInto('customerId=?', $comment->customerId);
$whereDate = $this->_getGateway()->getAdapter()->quoteInto('date=?', $comment->date);
$this->_getGateway()->update($data, array($whereId, $whereDate));
```